# How to answer Pin code with selenium c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automation

Very new to programming/selenium automation in C# and have hit a bit of a stumbling block that I am struggling at resolving, I have looked around on here / google but nothing has come up matching what I am looking for, I could be wording my question slightly wrong so forgive me if that is the case.

**What I need to achieve,** 
When logging into a website after entering a username/password we are prompted to enter a pin code, specifically a randomly generated combination – example “Please enter numbers 1, 2 & 3 of your PIN” - where (in the example) 1, 2, 3 can be anything from 1 to 6 (always chronological order), the message itself, “,” and “&” positions do not change – only the numbers.

** ***Info from the 'line' containing the message (and numbers)*** **

**Inner HTML**

Please enter numbers **1**, **3** & **5** of your PIN

**Outer HTML**

Please enter numbers **1**, **3** & **5** of your PIN

**CSS Selector**
h2.login-desktop-only

**xPath**
/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h2

For this situation I am using a ‘UAT site’ so I have control on the PIN, let’s say it is always 123456 – so 1 = 1, 2 =2, 3-3 and so on. I have no way to determine which numbers will be asked each time the test is run.

How can I ‘scrape’ the text from ‘Please enter numbers XXXXX’ and parse (I think that is the correct word) the data to separate the ‘scraped’ numbers and then in turn use that data to match the pre-declared ‘1 = 1’ etc etc to then end up selecting the correct number on the keypad?

I imagine this is going to need a list of IF statements but again I still do not know how to scrape / store the requested numbers. Ideally would like to keep this using c# (however if any Java examples exist I can work with that as a colleague is using java selenium - both of us are very new to this)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

(**EDIT TO Add code from comment**)

Many thanks for getting back to me, I tried that code and it has located the index position of the integers contained within that ‘string’. Currently it ‘prints’ out the index position, but how can I get that to give the value rather than print it? 
I suppose if I could assign it to a variable I could then split the three numbers down to a unique variable that has IF statements to cover the IF 1 – then 1 IF 2 – then 2 and so on. If that makes sense?

```
public class Some_Class {

public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

driver.get("SomeWebsite");

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("XXXXXXX ");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click(); 

/* --- This was my original plan to set the xpath as a string and then replace all with numbers only. This did not work as I thought. 
{
WebElement str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h2"));
String numberOnly = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
}
*/

WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h2"));

String word=option.getText();
String check[]=word.split("");
for(int i=0; i<check.length ; i++)
{
if( Pattern.matches("\\d", check[i]))
{
System.out.println("found integer at i = "+ i);


}
}


}
}
```

Comment: Currently I have,
found integer at i = 21
found integer at i = 24
found integer at i = 28

Answer (score 0):

Input : you need to scrape a string containing ' integers and alphabets' and return only integers.

Here's an example I have done using Selenium,Java.
Please change your URL and WebElement to scrape.

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

    WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"articlecount\"]"));
    String word=option.getText();
    //here you get - 5,589,206 articles in English
    String check[]=word.split("");
    for(int i=0; i<check.length ; i++)
     {
         if( Pattern.matches("\\d", check[i]))
         {
             System.out.println("found integer at i = "+ i);
         }
     }
```

Basically that would print you the index at which you have integers. Use them

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a challenge string that says

```
string pinRequest = "Please enter pin digits 1,4 & 8 of your pin.";

var pinNums = pinRequest.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray().ToList();
```

pinNums will be an integer array that has 3 parts which are equal to 
{1,4,8}

Your pin challenge is then solved via:

```
string part1 = fullWord.ToArray()[pinNums[0] - 1].ToString();
string part2 = fullWord.ToArray()[pinNums[1] - 1].ToString();
string part3 = fullWord.ToArray()[pinNums[2] - 1].ToString();
```

where fullWord could be something like 123123 or Password123

I am not too sure how this code will handle pin challenges >= 10 digits in length.